# add column to table and set value based on the value of another column

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have encountered the following issue: I have a table with several columns, now I need to add a new column to this table and then fill it with the encrypted (md5) value of another column.

1)

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD md5_city VARCHAR(255);
```

2)

```
"UPDATE myTable SET md5_city = " . md5($cityValue) . ";"
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why you would store same value twice?

Comment: MD5 is nbot encryption, it is a crytptographic hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have 3 separate tasks here:

1. Add the column
2. Update for existing values
3. Calculate for new values being inserted

**Task 1: Allow storage of MD5**

Your code is fine, but you should limit the size of the column as an MD5 will only ever be 32 characters in length

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD md5_city CHAR(32);
```

**Task 2: Update existing rows**

*Assuming you are using MSSQL and `col` contains < 8000 chars (4000 if NVARCHAR)*

The following SQL will calculate the MD5 of `col` for all existing rows and store it in the `md5_city` column. This should be run directly in SQL as a one off to update rows that are already within the table:

```
UPDATE myTable SET md5_city = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', col), 2)
```

**Task 3: Keep column up to date when performing updates to the table from PHP**

In your PHP, any update to `col` for a given row should update `city_md5` as well, such as:

```
$sql = "UPDATE myTable SET col = '{$x}', MD5_city = '" .md5($x). "' WHERE ID = 1";
```

Comment: can you elaborate what's happening in task2? You are taking myTable and setting any md5_city column value to .... what? I don't quite understand what is after the '='

Comment: I have edited the answer and hopefully clarified it a little. Task 2 is the calculation of the MD5 for all existing rows of `myTable` in MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Your method actually adds the column into the table.  One alternative is to calculate it on the fly:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD md5_city as md5(col);
```

This calculates the value only when you need it.

Comment: no, I actually need to add a new column and fill it with the md5 value of another column.

Comment: @user7808407 . . . A computed column is probably safer.  You don't need to work to keep it up-to-date.  And, you can persist it, so it is actually saved with the table.